# Understanding how kbuild build process work

Tags: makefile, kbuild

I am familiar with make and kbuild, and how the build system work. But I am having hard time understanding how the object goals are built!?

For example, in Kbuild, if you want to generate an object file in a directory you would have a makefile with something like:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_FOO) += foo.o
```

This evaluates to `obj-y/m` and adds `foo.o` to it, and I think that this build file is invoked using `submake`, then the main makefile would generate all **object goals** using either `obj-y` or `obj-m` (depending how/what you are building),right?

**My problem** is that usually you can pass from the main makefile/build file to its submake (i.e. `export`), but the `obj-y` variable is defined in many places so how is its value being constructed or tracked among all these `submake` invocations??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the whole build system for Busybox, I think I understand the logic behind it, so here is what I found out:

- There are shared makefiles in the scripts directory (e.g. makefile.build,  kbuild.include…etc) that contains common rules, build configurations, and other things.
- These shared makefiles are the ones that build the Kbuild makefiles (e.g. the ones that usually hold code like `obj-$(CONFIG_FOO) += foo.o`)
- How it works:

  - The *main makefile* do a **submake** invocation to `Makefile.build`, and passes a path/dir for the folder to be built (i.e. generate `built-in.o` from) as a *command line variable* (`obj`)
  - The `Makefile.build` file creates generic rules used to compile object goal files and to link them into `built-in.o`
  - Then the main makefile collects all `object-in.o` from the sub directories and link them together